Difference across rows in Pandas DataFrame
How do I create df2 directly using df as input? I can't wrap my head around it...
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'Year': [1990, 1990, 1990, 2022, 2022, 2022], 'City': ['Paris', 'Berlin', 'Lisbon', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Lisbon'], 'Population': [2.15, 3.40, 2.54, 2.11, 3.57, 2.99]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
   Year    City  Population
0  1990   Paris        2.15
1  1990  Berlin        3.40
2  1990  Lisbon        2.54
3  2022   Paris        2.11
4  2022  Berlin        3.57
5  2022  Lisbon        2.99
>>> data2 = {'City': ['Paris', 'Berlin', 'Lisbon'], 'Population change': [2.11 - 2.15, 3.57 - 3.40, 2.99 - 2.54]}
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
     City  Population change
0   Paris              -0.04
1  Berlin               0.17
2  Lisbon               0.45


Here is one way:
df['Pop change'] = df.groupby('City')['Population'].diff()
df2 = df.dropna().reset_index(drop = True).drop(['Year', 'Population'], axis = 1)

gives:
     City  Pop change
0   Paris       -0.04
1  Berlin        0.17
2  Lisbon        0.45


There are a couple of ways - @user19077881 is one of them. The options below are just alternatives:

with groupby (probably the most robust option)

(df
.sort_values('Year',ascending=False)
.groupby('City',sort=False,as_index=False)
.Population
.agg(np.subtract.reduce)
.rename(columns={'Population':'Population Change'})
)
     City  Population Change
0   Paris              -0.04
1  Berlin               0.17
2  Lisbon               0.45


with pivot - order is not maintained here (you can achieve that with a categorical)

(df
.pivot(index='City', columns='Year', values='Population')
.sort_index(axis=1,ascending=False)
.agg(np.subtract.reduce,axis=1)
.rename('Population Change')
.reset_index()
)

     City  Population Change
0  Berlin               0.17
1  Lisbon               0.45
2   Paris              -0.04


pivot and basic math (assuming only two years are present)

(df
.pivot(index='City', columns='Year', values='Population')
.pipe(lambda df: df[2022] - df[1990])
.rename('Population Change')
.reset_index()
)
     City  Population Change
0  Berlin               0.17
1  Lisbon               0.45
2   Paris              -0.04

resetting the index is not necessary (you get performance if you need to filter on the index labels).

This may help:
df['Population change'] = df['Population'].diff()

or use shift to view empty value on last:
df['Population change'] = df['Population'].diff().shift(-1)

